# gradle error while add sugar ORM 1.4 dependancy

Tags: android, sugarorm

after adding Sugar ORM dependency to gradle script  app file

```
dependencies {
   compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
   testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
   compile 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.4'
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
   compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
   compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.4.0'
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
   compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}
```

Gradle complied my project, but  once I tried to run it in a physical device  (via Android studio) I got this error :

**Error:Your app has more methods references than can fit in a single dex file.
See https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html**

There are now errors If I tried to compile and run  the app with Sugar ORM 1.3

Has the library grown  so large in version 1.4 it will no longer fit into a single  DEX ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable multiDex support by using:

```
defaultConfig {        
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

in your build.gradle (app)
Hope this help!